# Is a Fibre port the same as a WAN port?

Tags: port, wan

I have a DSL-3780 router from TalkTalk which has a RJ45 port labelled Fibre, then LAN1/2/3/4. Is this Fibre port a WAN port where I can connect it to the data port on a VDSL faceplate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely, yes it is.  This is the WAN port that comes from the companies "fibre" modem.